# I am having problems with these command. Data type mismatch in criteria expression. can you help me?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

`SELECT * FROM swiftRecord WHERE recID =localID`.    recID is an autonumber from access database. localID is declared as an integer.

```
Integer localID = Integer.parseInt(Global.uniNum.getText());
localID++;
System.out.println(localID);                
try
{

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Global.database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\DB\\swift_db_14.accdb;";
Global.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Global.database, "", "");
Global.s = Global.conn.createStatement();
Global.rs = Global.s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM swiftRecord WHERE recID = '" + localID +"' " );                               
String payLine1="";
int cou = 0;
while(Global.rs.next())
{
payLine1=Global.rs.getString("payLine1");
cou++;
}
System.out.println(payLine1);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am trying to get the values from a database called swiftRecord. and i am trying to pull up data by specifying the recID which is unique. i get a data mismatch everytime i run the program.

Comment: Show the actual code you used...

Comment: hi MadProgrammer, i have added the code i used.

Answer (score 1):

This is the second time today I've seen this exact same problem...

The problem is, when you enclose your `localID` variable in quotes, `'" + localID +"'`, it gets treat as a `String`

Instead...

Use [`PreapredStatement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) or remove the quote

```
"SELECT * FROM swiftRecord WHERE recID = " + localID;
```

Seriously, use [`PreapredStatement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: so it means that i wont have to change my query statement? just the declaration?